# Как сделать так, чтобы при увеличении изображения не появлялась полоса прокрутки?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Есть галерея картинок, которые при наведении увеличиваются в размерах. Как сделать так, чтобы картинки продолжали увеличиваться точно также, может только более плавно (заезжали на соседние элементы **включая верхние и нижние полосы**), но при этом не появлялась горизонтальная полоса прокрутки на последнем элементе?

Код: [фидл](http://jsfiddle.net/r04m5hqj/3/)

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}
.yellow {
  background-color:yellow;
  height:30px;
}
.red {
  background-color:red;
  height:30px;
}
#photos {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: space-around;
 align-items: baseline;
}
 .photo {
  display: flex;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 20%;
  height: 150px;
 }
 .photo:hover {
     transform: scale(1.1);
     transition: .5s all;
     -webkit-transition: .5s all;
     -moz-transition: .5s all;
     -o-transition: .5s all;
     -ms-transition: .5s all;
 }
 #photo-1 {
  background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/150x150");
 }
 #photo-2 {
  background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/150x150");
 }
 #photo-3 {
  background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/150x150");
 }
 #photo-4 {
  background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/150x150");
 }
 #photo-5 {
  background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/150x150");
 }
```

```html
<div class="yellow"></div>
   <div id="photos">
     <a class="photo" id="photo-1"></a>
     <a class="photo" id="photo-2"></a>
     <a class="photo" id="photo-3"></a>
     <a class="photo" id="photo-4"></a>
     <a class="photo" id="photo-5"></a>
    </div>
<div class="red"></div>
```

Comment: @Геннадий Журов пробовал, но не то - я специально прописывал (выделил жирным, чтобы было заметнее), что картинки должны налезать на верхнюю и нижнюю полоску. `overflow-x` и `overflow-y` тоже не спасают

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример с `transform-origin`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 30px;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
  height: 30px;
}

#photos {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: baseline;
}

.photo {
  display: block;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position:center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  width: 20%;
  height: 150px;
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

.photo:hover {
  transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.1);
  transition: .5s all;
  -webkit-transition: .5s all;
  -moz-transition: .5s all;
  -o-transition: .5s all;
  -ms-transition: .5s all;
}

.photo:last-child {
  transform-origin: right center;
}

#photo-1 {
  background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/150x150");
}

#photo-2 {
  background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/150x150");
}

#photo-3 {
  background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/150x150");
}

#photo-4 {
  background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/150x150");
}

#photo-5 {
  background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/150x150");
}
```

```html
<div class="yellow"></div>
<div id="photos">
  <a class="photo" id="photo-1"></a>
  <a class="photo" id="photo-2"></a>
  <a class="photo" id="photo-3"></a>
  <a class="photo" id="photo-4"></a>
  <a class="photo" id="photo-5"></a>
</div>
<div class="red"></div>
```

Comment: да, спасибо! А с плавностью появления картинки (без артефактов по бокам) можно что-нить сделать?

Comment: Видел я тут один приём с `translateZ(0)` https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/849712/275019 , вроде с большего убирает. Ответ обновил.